# AWS s3 -trigger on object created, function gets invoked continuously

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I've created a lambda function to read a file (input.csv) from s3 bucket and make some changes into it and save that file(output.csv) in same bucket.
Note: i have not deleted input.csv file in bucket.
The lambda function is triggered with object-created(All) event. But the function is called continuously like infinite number of times as input file is present in bucket.
Is is supposed to happen like this ? or Is it fault?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is your fault :)

You have set up a recursive trigger - each time you update the file, you're actually writing a new copy of it, which triggers the event, etc.

This was a key warning in the initial demo when Lambda was released (an image is uploaded to S3, lambda is triggered to create a thumbnail - if that thumbnail is written to the same bucket, it will trigger again, etc)

Answer (score 7):

As @chris has pointed out, you've triggered a recursive loop by having events triggered by an S3 PUT event, which in turns performs another PUT, calling the trigger again and again.

To avoid this problem, the simplest method is to use two S3 buckets - one for files to be placed prior to processing, and another for files to be placed post-processing.

If you don't want to use two S3 buckets, you can modify your trigger condition to include FilterRules ([docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html#notification-how-to-filtering)). This allows you to control the trigger such that it would only get executed when an object is placed in a certain "folder" in S3 (of course folders don't really exist in S3, they're just key prefixes).

Here's an example:

```
{
    "LambdaFunctionConfigurations": [
        {
            "Filter": {
                "Key": {
                    "FilterRules": [
                        {
                            "Name": "Prefix", 
                            "Value": "queue/"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }, 
            "LambdaFunctionArn": <lambda_func_arn>, 
            "Id": "<lambda_func_name>:app.lambda_handler", 
            "Events": [
                "s3:ObjectCreated:*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```